# How do I fake Action<string>

Tags: c#

I have a console application.

When I invoke the logic, I pass in an Action in order to display to the console.

My console application looks a little like

```
static Main(string[] args)
{
    var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(WriteToConsole);
    //…. more code
}

static void WriteToConsole(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Sorry if code isn't perfect, I don't have Visual Studio here so doing it from memory.

Now, I need to test my code. I'd like to simulate the WriteToConsole with a duff method, which essentially does nothing.

What I'd like to do is in my unit test is

```
var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(new Action<string>());
```

But this does not work.

I'm not using any DI framework so can't mock anything (nor do I want to).

I know a solution is to simply create a method that matches the signature but I'm curious if this is possible in a way I've described above?

Comment: `var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(s => Console.WriteLine(s));` Or you can just have it do nothing at all: `var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(x => {});`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass in a lambda expression that does nothing for an `Action<string>` easily enough.

Something along the lines of the following should work, and do nothing when called:

```
var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(_ => {});
```

If you prefer you can always create a method that does nothing as a  delegate conversion.

```
void DoNothing(string val) { return; }
...
var myLogicClass = new LogicClass(DoNothing);
```

Comment: Hmmmm… I don't feel like it's "nice" code but it solves the issue perfectly!

Comment: `_ => {}` should work in earlier versions, it just creates a variable called `_`.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions You can just as easily create a void method that takes a string and does nothing, then pass that as a method group to delegate conversion. I've edited my post to show this.

Comment: *"I know a solution is to simply create a method that matches the signature but I'm curious if this is possible in a way I've described above"* implies that your edit isn't necessary. I'm curious why @MyDaftQuestions thinks this isn't nice code.

Comment: Sorry @RufusL , by not nice code, I think I'm voicing my personal opinion about code style. Sorry, I shouldn't open that can of works. The underscore just looks bleugh. I guess instead of not nice, I should have used the term unfamiliar :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to verify that the action was invoked:

```
var actionInvoked = false;
Action<string> action = (s) => actionInvoked = true; 
var subject = new LogicClass(action);
```

Or, for brevity:

```
var subject = new LogicClass((s) => actionInvoked = true);
```

Then you can assert that `actionInvoked` is true.